# How to list all available Python packages including their versions on a (private) PyPi package repository?

Tags: python, pip, gitlab, pypi, twine

We are maintaining a [private PyPi repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/) on a GitLab instance in which we upload hundreds of Python wheels for different platforms, architectures and Python versions in order to use them internally.

As the amount of packages grows, we only want to upload packages that do not already exist in the repository and thus, want to to check what's already available in advance. We have looked into [`pip search`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_search/) but it only seems to work for single packages.

Is there any way to check for all available packages on a package repository including their versions, architectures, etc.?

I was hoping for something like `pip list` but for the repository.